# Как обновить область уведомлений Windows?

Tags: c++, winapi

Меняю в реестре флаг "EnableAutoTray" чтобы всегда выводились или скрывались значки в области уведомлений. Только одного изменения в реестре не достаточно, чтобы изменения отразились в системе - нужно закрыть explorer и запустить заново. Гуглил методы обновления проводника, чтобы без kill-process'а обойтись, но что-то пока не работает... Код следующий:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
//expupdatetest
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    if (argc > 1){
        HKEY RegKey;
        unsigned long value = atoi(argv[1]);
        switch(value){
            case 0:
            case 1:
                RegCreateKeyEx(
                        HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
                        "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\", 
                        0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, &RegKey, NULL);
                RegSetValueEx(RegKey, "EnableAutoTray", 0, REG_DWORD, (BYTE*)&value, sizeof(value));
                RegCloseKey(RegKey);
                // Попытка сообщить окнам, что что-то поменялось...
                SendMessageA(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, 0) ;
                break;
            default:
                std::cout << "ERROR! Value must be 0 or 1\n";
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Чего тут не хватает, чтобы иконки сразу скрылись при `value == 1`, и появились при нуле?**